# How can I set object variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Unfortunately, I ran into a error that I can't fix.
At first glance, everything seems to be fine.
The code marked *** *** itself is the same as the previous lines, but this particular part causes an error.

```
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set.
```

The rest of the code compiles without any problem.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim copyOsoby As Range
    Dim pasteOsoby As Range
    Dim pastePunktacja As Range
    ***'Dim pasteWyplaty As Range***

    Set copyOsoby = Sheets("DODAJ_OSOBE").ListObjects("Osoby").DataBodyRange
    Set pasteBaza = Sheets("BAZA_KAIZEN").ListObjects("Baza").DataBodyRange
    Set pastePunktacja = Sheets("PUNKTACJA").ListObjects("Punkty").DataBodyRange
    ***'Set pasteWyplaty = Sheets("WYPLATY").ListObjects("Wyplaty").DataBodyRange***

    copyOsoby.Copy pasteBaza.Offset(pasteBaza.Rows.Count)
    copyOsoby.Copy pastePunktacja.Offset(pastePunktacja.Rows.Count)
    ***'copyOsoby.Copy pasteWyplaty.Offset(pasteWyplaty.Rows.Count)***


    pastePunktacja.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    ***'pasteWyplaty.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes***


    Sheets("DODAJ_OSOBE").ListObjects("Osoby").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

   End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the tips / error indication.

Comment: Your list contains no data, so its `DataBodyRange` is `Nothing`.

Comment: Is there a sheet named "WYPLATY", with a table named "Wyplaty", having data in `DataBodyRange`?

Comment: Yes. I created sheet named "WYPLATY" and table named "Wyplaty".
This table does not have any data just like table "Baza" and table "Punktacja".
Copy-paste data from table "Osoby" is working perfectly for these tables.

Comment: `just like table "Baza" and table "Punktacja"` - there is a difference for Excel. If a ListObject has only one row that contained data before but now doesn't, `DataBodyRange` is not nothing. If you "Delete cells" in that empty row, it will then look the same, but `DataBodyRange` will now be Nothing.

Comment: Oh. I see it now. Thank you for explanation and your time.